# Sourcing .bashrc inside script doesn't update the env variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I have a long installation script that frequently inserts env variables into .bashrc for immediate and future use, then sources `.bashrc` to update the env variables. However, this is not working as intended. Unlike when run independently in terminal, running these commands together as a script fails to update the current environment.

Here's a small example:

```
echo export TEST_BASH=sup >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
echo $TEST_BASH
```

The final line will print empty rather than 'sup' as intended. Why is that?

Comment: What shell are you executing these commands in?  The `dash` shell (`/bin/sh` on some Linuxes) does not have `source`.  Also, if any code in `~/.bashrc` _stops_ the sourcing of the file to the end (possibly depending on whether it's being sourced by an interactive shell or not), the variable would obviously not be set.

Comment: I'm using `#!/bin/bash`. Interesting idea that the file might stop. It's just the plain `.bashrc` file generated by Ubuntu 16.04 with 4 exports for env vars.

Comment: at least on debian, the default ~/.bashrc starts with something like `case $- in *i*) ;; *) return ;; esac`. So, if the shell is not interactive, `source ~/.bashrc` will return immediately, and any lines you may add at the end have no effect.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's the case here as well.

Comment: I'll have a separate `.bash_myenv` file and then just source that instead, and add a line to `.bashrc` to source that one. Thanks! Feel free to provide your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `~/.bashrc` file detects whether it's being sourced by an interactive or non-interactive shell:

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
    *) return ;;
esac
```

When this file is sourced from a script (which is a non-interactive shell), the `return` branch is taken and the file does not execute to the end.

Adding `export` statements to the end of the file would mean that these would not be executed when sourced from a script.

The solution may be to write the `export` statements to a separate file and source that from your script (and possibly from `~/.bashrc` as well if you think its needed).